# Angular Checkbox Range does not work

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, module, shift

I use the [Angular Checkbox Range](http://schlogen.github.io/angular-multi-check/), but it does not work. This is my html code:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/angular.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/angular-multi-check.js')}}"></script>
<script>
angular.module("app",["angular-multi-check"]);
<script>


<ul  multi-check-group class="list-unstyled" style="font-family: 'verdana', 'Microsoft YaHei', 'Consolas', 'Deja Vu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono';">
 <li ng-repeat="s in vm.data | filter: { label:vm.query }">
<input id="" multi-check type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px;" ng-model="s.check" value="[[ s.label ]]">[[ s.label ]]
</li>
</ul>
```

```
angular.module("app",["angular-multi-check"])->report an error:
          [$injector:unpr] angular.min.js(line 92)
```

(version 1.2.22;1,3,3 also not work).

What should I do?

Comment: Is this you complete html? Where is `ng-app` declaration?

Comment: @ Chandermani:yes. html->body->div ng-app="app"->div ng-control="BigCtrl as vm"->div panel ->div panel-body->div ng-isolate-scope->div row ->div col-lg-5 ->div filter ->ul  ,this is the structure

Comment: Forgive my ignorance！angular.module() is defined in a js, just add a dependency to  angular module like  angular.module('app',['angular-muti-check',.....]) and it will work.